# Get the class from the type itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to do a generic method to bind all the dropdownlist to its respective DB Table in SQL (testing purposes only). I am using Entity framework. I almost did, but I think I am stuck on an imposible task (at least no desirable), get the DbSet whichever is. Here is the code:

```
...
List<WebControl> myWebControl = new List<WebControl>();

GetWholeControls<WebControl>(Controls, ref myWebControl); //Get all the controls in the page

myDBentity = new TimeSheetDBEntity(); /My EF


foreach (WebControl childControl in myWebControl) //Loop all the controls
{
    if (childControl is DropDownList) //Get only ddl controls
    {

         List<Type> typelist = (List<Type>)from p in typeof(TimeSheetDBEntity).GetProperties()
                                                      where p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>)
                                                      select p.Name; //get all DBSet properties of my EF

          foreach (Type currentType in typelist) //Loop the properties
          {
              if (childControl.ID == currentType.Name) //Compare with the ddl controls name (the first one is for example Product
              {

                 ((DropDownList)childControl).DataSource = myDBentity.Product.ToList(); //HOW TO GET PRODUCT BACK!!
                 ((DropDownList)childControl).DataTextField = "Name";
                 ((DropDownList)childControl).DataValueField = "Name";
                 ((DropDownList)childControl).DataBind();
               }              
            }
       }
}
....



public static void GetWholeControls<T>(ControlCollection pageControls, ref List<T> myWebControl)
    where T : Control
{
    foreach (Control control in pageControls)
    {
        if (control is T)
            myWebControl.Add((T)control);

         if (control.HasControls())
            GetWholeControls(control.Controls, ref myWebControl);
    }
}
```

I want to get the 'Product' type so I can them get the list of items and put them in the ddl. Of course the control name and class type name are equal ("Product") and the textfield/valuefield are always "Name". I think it cannot be achieved in a normal way cause I cannot create a compile-time type from a type known only at runtime...maybe using reflection or Activator.CreateInstance?...

Comment: What do you mean "get back the class"? A new instance of the class?

Comment: Agree. Clutter code and poor explanation. I am going to edit it, trying to explain myself. Basically I just want to get the DbSet<type> that match the above criteria, at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework context has a method to get a set by type as opposed to directly accessing the DbSet property

So, instead of `myDBEntity.Products.ToList();`, you could call `myDBEntity.Set(currentType)AsQueryable().ToList()`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set(System.Type)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this but, set(Type), only returns a DbSet and not DbSet<>, so I am afraid we dont have ToList() here. Do I missing an extra step?

Comment: It does return a types DbSet, you may have to put .AsQueryable (), i will update answer

Comment: you mean? myDBentity.Set(currentType).AsQueryable().ToListAsync(). I think you also forgot one dot. Anyway I reworked all my code with another solution and is working now. Thank you for you effort.